# White space at top of page after converting .net project to use layouts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I recently changed my .net project to use master pages / layout pages. Now when all of my page are rendered there is some space at the top of the page right before navbar.

[image]

I inspected that page in chrome, there is some empty quotes at the top of body, Removing those in the inspector solves the issue. but I am unable to understand where does they comes from? Here is my index's page structure.

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  ViewBag.Title = "my title";
}
<!--HERO IMAGE-->
<div>
    //index page's code comes here
</div>

@section additionalStyles{
   //adding external stylesheets
}
```

I am using render section in my index page to load some style sheets not useful in the rest of the pages. These are loaded up right before the ending  tag in layout page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

  <!-- All STYLESHEETS ARE ADDED AT THIS PLACE-->

  @RenderSection("additionalStyles", required: false);
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
       //navbar's code  comes here
  </div>

    @RenderBody();

  <!-- FOOTER -->

  @RenderSection("additionalScripts", required: false);

  <!-- ALL SCRIPTS ARE ADDED HERE-->
</body>
</html>
```

What possibly be causing that quotes?

**P.s: I just noticed many of my pages are getting that spacing and quotes so they are probably coming from layout files or probably these sections are causing the issue but i don't exactly know how to solve it**

**EDIT :** A second page which actually define both of the sections to be rendered by the layout page, is actually getting three of those """quotes""".

- at the end of the first renderSection(additionalStyles)
- one at the end of the content placed by renderBody()
- and one at the end of the content placed by renderSection(additionalScripts)

Is this some pattern?

Comment: Provide more code please.

Comment: i added layout page's structure as well.

Comment: Maybe add a screenshot of the Chrome inspector so we can see where the quotes are being inserted.

Comment: i actually added a screenshot

probably removed it by mistake, let me re add it.

Comment: @sleeyuen added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely it is inserting semicolon `;`.

```
@RenderSection("additionalStyles", required: false);

@RenderBody();
```

Your code has unnecessary semicolons after the `@RenderSection`s and are generating them for display. Remove them and that "space" goes away.

See Section 3 of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c for semicolon usage.

> 3. Inside a block, you end each code statement with a semicolon
>
>    Inside a code block, each complete code statement must end with a semicolon. Inline expressions don't end with a semicolon.

```
<!-- Single-statement block -->
@{ var theMonth = DateTime.Now.Month; }

<!-- Multi-statement block -->
@{
    var outsideTemp = 79;
    var weatherMessage = "Hello, it is " + outsideTemp + " degrees.";
}

<!-- Inline expression, so no semicolon -->
<p>Today's weather: @weatherMessage</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've got a stray semi-colon (;) in the layout. I'd check the layout page for any stray or repeating semi-colons (eg they could be mistakenly repeated ;;). Also check the _ViewStart.cshtml file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue is with the semicolons at the end of your `@RenderSection`s and `@RenderBody`. Those don't take semis:

```
@RenderSection("additionalStyles", required: false)
@RenderBody()
```